# ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have the problem with function `JSON.parse()`

I used this because my data from a web server are always a string.
I have this JSON

```
 {
        "StatusCode": 0,
        "StatusMessage": "OK",
        "StatusDescription": 
           [
             {
                "id": "1",
                "datetime": "2018-04-13",
                "data":"{ "id_data": "1S1S2ED333", "model": "02S", "serial_data": "123456" }"
             }
           ]
          }
```

I want to convert this string

`"{ "id_data": "1S1S2ED333", "model": "02S", "serial_data": "123456" }"`

*to:*

```
{id_data: "1S1S2ED333", model: "02S",serial_data:"123456"}
```

I tried to convert:

```
 export class Product{
        id: number;
        datetime: Date;
        data: string;

        constructor(obj: any) {
            this.id= obj.id;
            this.datetime= obj.datetime;
            this.data = obj.data;  //show "data":"{ "id_data": "1S1S2ED333", "model": "02S", "serial_data": "123456" }"
            this.data= JSON.parse(this.data); // show ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
            this.data = typeof this.data == "object"? this.data : typeof this.data == "string"? JSON.parse(this.data) : {}; `//show data:{}`
            this.data = obj && JSON.stringify(this.data ); //undefined

            }
public generateUrlencodedParameters(token: string, id?: number): string {

    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
          urlSearchParams.append('data', this.data.toString());
          urlSearchParams.append('datatime', this.datatime.toString());
          urlSearchParams.append('token', token);
    return urlSearchParams.toString();
     }
    }
```

Can you suggest me, what is the problem?

I want to display in html those data.

When I tried

```
<table *ngFor="let item of products">
   <tr>{{item.id}}</tr>
   <tr>{{item.datatime}}</tr>
   <tr>{{item.data}}</tr> //show all string { "id_data": "1S1S2ED333", "model": "02S", "serial_data": "123456" }
</table>
```

I want to show only `model` and `serial_data` for this I have to do the string processing

Comment: You have no "u" letter at first position of the JSON sample you shared. My guess is that `this.data` comes as "undefined".. can you `console.log` it to check?

Comment: I edit my post please

Comment: Isn't that a malformed JSON? [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) failed to parse it.. The quotes should be escaped

Comment: @MasterPo My data, I want to convert in a correct Json

Comment: Can you try `JSON.parse(this.data.replace(/"/g, '\\"'))`?. It escapes all the double quotes in the string before parse

Answer (score 0):

This problem is may be coming due to two reasons

First => your `data` is already parsed or not coming string so do this for this

`this.data = typeof this.data == "object"? this.data : typeof this.data == "string"? JSON.parse(this.data) : {};`

Second => Check your Json I think something might be wrong.

I am not sure It will work or not because your JSON is not coming in right format specially data property. I would suggest you to send JSON in proper format from server

```
this.data =JSON.parse(this.data.replace(new RegExp('}"',"g"),"}").replace(new RegExp('"{',"g"),"{").trim())
```

Comment: When I tried this code, my data are empty. `data:{}`

Comment: Ok Can you check what typeof of this.data is coming?

Comment: You can do this also in order to check `typeof` :- `this.data = typeof this.data`

Comment: As you updated ` this.data` , can you update your question with full value of ` this.data`

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not really understand what you are looking for. I'm modifying my post again. Thank you

Comment: Note that It is a temporary solution, Send right JSON from server.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that, in your constructor (at least in what you shared with us):

```
this.data = JSON.parse(this.data);
```

But you never assign `this.data` before to anything, so it is `undefined` and `JSON.parse` fails.